# Angular isolate scope value can be set by "true" or empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom angular directive which for the sake of brevity we'll just call map.

It has an isolate scope set up like this.

```
scope: {
    latitude: '=?',
    longitude: '=?',
    draggable: '=?'
},
```

I normally put something in my link function which sets scope values to be either what has been set in the attribute, or a default if nothing has been set so the devoloper can add draggable="false" if they want, otherwise we'll automatically default it to true, so in the link function I would have this.

```
$scope.draggable = angular.isDefined($scope.draggable) ? $scope.draggable : myDefaults.draggable;
```

The problem is that I want all of the following to be valid uses in html

```
<map draggable></map>
<map draggable="true"></map>
<map draggable="false"></map>
```

but the first line won't work because angular.isDefined() is false.

Should I check whether it is defined first and if it isn't then use something like attrs.draggable to see if the attribute exists before falling back on the default?

If so then there is a further complication because I need to put my code in the controller not the link function (because it needs to talk to child directives) and I don't have access to "attrs" or "element" from the controller.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use scope variables in your `draggable` attribute, just use the `$attrs` parameter in the directive's `link` function for all four of your use cases:

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    if ("draggable" in $attrs) {
        $scope.draggable = $scope.draggable === "" || $attrs.draggable === "true";
    } else {
        $scope.draggable = myDefaults.draggable;
    }
}
```

Explanation: If the `draggable` attribute doesn't exist, it will not be in the `$attrs` object. If it exists but is not set, it will be equal to empty string. If it exists and is set, it will equal the string value you set it to: `"true"` or `"false"`.

If you use `$attrs`, don't worry about assigning draggable via the `scope` property of your directive -- it will get overwritten.

Note, as mentioned above, this solution won't allow you to bind scope variables to the attribute. For that, you'll have to use the `scope` property on your directive.

For the curious, [the link function](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom).

Comment: Thanks, but will that be true for `<map draggable></map>` ? unless I am wrong I think that would be false

Comment: @jonhobbs For `<map draggable></map>`, `$attrs.draggable` will be undefined in the `link` function, in which case `myDefaults.draggable` will be used.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I need it to be true when draggable attribute exists but is not set, that's why I'm struggling :)

Comment: @jonhobbs I was wrong about what `$attrs.draggable` would equal when it existed but was not set. See my edited answer.

Comment: That's nearly right, but it should only use the default if the attribute is omitted. If it exists and is not set it should be true, if it is set then it should be true if it is anything other than draggable='false'. However there seems to be a bigger problem here because I am using a =? binding and the more I read the more it seems as if there is no way to use a two way binding AND allow a string/bool/expression to be used optionally, so it's not possible to have draggable="'false'" and draggable="controllerScopeVariable" using the same binding.

Comment: I'm thinking about using 2 separate attributes, one for setting initial values and one for 2 way bindings. E.g. draggable="true" and draggable-model="myMap.draggable". It's not as neat in the HTML but is it less hacky?

Comment: @jonhobbs I guess I misunderstood. Let me see if this is right: in the case of `<map draggable></map>`, draggable is true, in `<map draggable="true"></map>`, draggable is true, in `<map draggable="false"></map>` draggable is false, in `<map></map>` draggable is default? If that's correct, I can certainly update the answer.

You're probably right about the two-way binding. I assumed because of your use cases that you would actually just use "true" and "false" as attribute values. If you want to bind them, you probably want to use `scope`.

Comment: @jonhobbs I updated the answer for the clarified use cases.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I came up with but your previous answer led me to it.